# TS Non-abstract class interpreted as abstract

Tags: typescript, abstract-class, abstract

I'm trying to instantiate a non-abstract class `C` that inherits from an abstract class `B` (that is itself derived from abstract class `A`), but Typescript is insisting that `C` cannot be instantiated because it is abstract. All three classes are written in ES2015 with the following `d.ts` files:

**In `A.d.ts`**

```
declare abstract class A {
  constructor(opts?: { opt: boolean});

  /* Abstract and concrete methods */
}
```

**In `B.d.ts`**

```
declare abstract class B extends A {
  abstract a(): void;
  abstract b(foo: string): Promise<Bar[]>;
  abstract c(foo: string): Promise<Bar>;
  abstract d(foo: string, v: any): Promise<any>;
  abstract e(foo: string): Promise<any>;

  f(foo: string, bar: number, baz: string): string;
}
```

**In `C.d.ts`**

```
declare class C extends B {
  constructor(opts?: { opt: boolean });

  a(): void;
  b(foo: string): Promise<Bar[]>;
  c(foo: string): Promise<Bar>;
  d(foo: string, v: any): Promise<any>;
  e(foo: string): Promise<any>;

  f(foo: string, bar: number, baz: string): string;
}
```

In another project, I import `C` and call `new C({ opt: true })`, and get the error message `Cannot create an instance of the abstract class 'C'.` I figure that there's something wrong with my declaration files, but I can't find anything on SO or [typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) that indicates what it is. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't create a class that you've `declare`d in a definition. You have to have an actually class in a non-definition file in order to create an instance of it.

Comment: Is their a concrete implementation of class C somewhere?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan So you're saying that the ES2015 versions of these classes don't 'count' from typescript's point of view? I thought that's what declaration files were for?

Comment: @Martin yes, but in .js files rather than .ts. I wrote the declaration files so that I could use class C in a Typescript project

Comment: TypeScript is its own language, optionally transpiled to ES2015. If you want to use TypeScript, use TypeScript with .ts files. If you want to use ES2015, use ES2015 with .js files. I don't believe the intent was to mix the two.

Comment: The goal here is to consume an ES2015 library in a typescript setting. So, the .d.ts files *should* be able to allow use of the javascript library in an ng2/ts app, right?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a typo in the declaration files: in `B.d.ts`, I had `export as namespace BTypo;` instead of `export as namespace B;`, which in turn must have confused Typescript as to how `C` implemented the abstract methods of `A` and `B`.